# Is there any website built by HTML frames? Should I learn this topic?

Tags: html, frame

I almost completed to learn HTML and now I started to learn CSS.

The last topic of HTML learning on my book is HTML Frames. But this topic seems me so boring. Actually I skip this topic, because there is no any website touched in my Internet Accessing experience which use the HTML frames!!!

Perhaps I'm wrong.

So my question: "Is there any website built by HTML frames? Should I learn it?"

Comment: What are HTML frames?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_rows

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_mix

Comment: What book are you using that is talking about this technology which was mainly used in the 90s?

Comment: Throw away that book and find a new one.

Comment: It's in my native language...

Comment: Then find another one in your native language.

Comment: I'm going to e-mail publication for modification in reprint. Actually I learn HTML from many sources. Only this book have the topic of Frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** It is an extremely old concept that has been out of use for a *long* time, and is now even deprecated in the spec and may eventually stop working / being supported in browsers.

When I started building websites seriously about 10 years ago they were an old and long out of general use concept *then*.

If you were bored and just wanted to learn it for historical purposes then have fun. But there is absolutely no practical value in knowing frames.

**Skip it.** *In fact, just tear those pages out. They're not even worth the added weight to the book.*

---

*Note: `iframes` are a completely different thing and are very much in use and you should know them...just specifically frames forget about.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see

This is a fact...

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp)

and...

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp)

```
HTML frameset Tag. Not Supported in HTML5.

HTML frame Tag. Not Supported in HTML5.
```

This is an opinion...

Your next question is should you learn it. This is up to you. I would focus on more relevant information but learning things that are no longer supported could be of use to you.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'NO',

You don't have to, or should I say you don't have the need to do so, since HTML5 doesn't support it.